# Basic solving for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some really basic chemistry but I am having problems with some of the math involved. Basically I just need help solving $x$ for this question and I think that I am good.
$$Ka=X^2/0.500=1.8 × 10^{-5}.$$
According to the textbook the answer is $X=3.0 × 10^{-3}$, so how do I find $X$?

Comment: Is it $$\frac{x^2}{0.5}=1.8\cdot 10^{-5}x$$?

Comment: Yes except without the X at the end of 1.8x10^-5

Answer (score 1):

You have $\dfrac{X^2}{0.500} = 1.8\cdot10^{-5}$

$\implies X^2 = 1.8\cdot0.500\cdot 10^{-5}$

$\implies X^2 =  0.90 \;\cdot\;10^{-5}$

$\implies X = \sqrt{9.00  \;\cdot\;10^{-6}}$

$\implies X = 3\cdot10^{-3}$

Comment: How did the 0.90 and 10^-5 become 9.00 and 10^-6?

Comment: $0.9\cdot10^{-5} = 9\cdot 10^{-1}\cdot10^{-5} = 9 \cdot 10^{-6}$ this is based on the law of exponents that $a^n\cdot a^m =a^{n+m}$ and $\frac1{a^m} = a^{-m}$